# Compute weekly average for past four complete weeks

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL DB (Version 5.5.31) say table_1 with description:

```
mysql> desc table_1;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| col_1 | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| col_2 | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| col_3 | date        | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| col_4 | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| col_5 | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| col_6 | float       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| col_7 | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1
(
col_1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
col_2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
col_3 DATE NOT NULL,
col_4 INT(11) NOT NULL,
col_5 INT(11) NOT NULL,
col_6 FLOAT NOT NULL,
col_7 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (col_1, col_2, col_3)
);
```

**What I have:**
This table will have percentage values of col_4 against col_5 in col_6. (col_5/col4 * 100). The table will be updated once a day. Col_7 is timestamp of update. I have populated it with sample data using:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7)
VALUES('String_1', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-29', 22166, 13772, 62.1312, '2018-03-29 15:01:55'),
('String_1', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-29', 22166, 512, 2.30984, '2018-03-29 15:01:55'),
('String_1', 'String_6', '2018-03-29', 22166, 3325, 15.0005, '2018-03-29 15:01:55'),
('STRING_2', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-29', 13118, 7329, 55.8698, '2018-03-29 15:02:03'),
('STRING_2', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-29', 13118, 0, 0, '2018-03-29 15:02:03'),
('STRING_2', 'String_6', '2018-03-29', 13118, 109, 0.830919, '2018-03-29 15:02:03'),
('String_3', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-29', 334, 15, 4.49102, '2018-03-29 15:02:06'),
('String_3', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-29', 334, 0, 0, '2018-03-29 15:02:06'),
('String_3', 'String_6', '2018-03-29', 334, 8, 2.39521, '2018-03-29 15:02:06'),
('String_1', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-30', 22166, 13778, 62.1583, '2018-03-30 04:00:15'),
('String_1', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-30', 22166, 256, 1.15492, '2018-03-30 04:00:15'),
('String_1', 'String_6', '2018-03-30', 22166, 3325, 15.0005, '2018-03-30 04:00:15'),
('STRING_2', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-30', 13118, 7327, 55.8545, '2018-03-30 04:00:22'),
('STRING_2', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-30', 13118, 0, 0, '2018-03-30 04:00:22'),
('STRING_2', 'String_6', '2018-03-30', 13118, 109, 0.830919, '2018-03-30 04:00:22'),
('String_3', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-30', 333, 14, 4.2042, '2018-03-30 04:00:25'),
('String_3', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-30', 333, 0, 0, '2018-03-30 04:00:25'),
('String_3', 'String_6', '2018-03-30', 333, 8, 2.4024, '2018-03-30 04:00:25'),
('String_1', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-31', 22165, 13778, 62.1611, '2018-03-31 04:00:09'),
('String_1', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-31', 22165, 512, 2.30995, '2018-03-31 04:00:09'),
('String_1', 'String_6', '2018-03-31', 22165, 3335, 15.0462, '2018-03-31 04:00:09'),
('STRING_2', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-31', 13119, 7327, 55.8503, '2018-03-31 04:00:17'),
('STRING_2', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-31', 13119, 0, 0, '2018-03-31 04:00:17'),
('STRING_2', 'String_6', '2018-03-31', 13119, 112, 0.853724, '2018-03-31 04:00:17'),
('String_3', 'STRING_4', '2018-03-31', 333, 14, 4.2042, '2018-03-31 04:00:20'),
('String_3', 'StrIng_5', '2018-03-31', 333, 0, 0, '2018-03-31 04:00:20'),
('String_3', 'String_6', '2018-03-31', 333, 8, 2.4024, '2018-03-31 04:00:20');
```

**What I want to do** is run a SQL every Saturday and go back 4 complete weeks (Sunday-Saturday is one complete week) and compute weekly average of col_6 for each distinct combination of col_2 & col_3.

```
select distinct col_2, col_1 from table_1 order by col_2, col_1;
```

So for this sample data, I am trying to get output like:
[image: ExpectedResult]

**What I have tried:**
I have started with something like which gives me average for all the past data:

```
select count(distinct col_3) from table_1;

select col_2, col_1, round(avg(col_6))
  from table_1
 group by col_2, col_1;
```

I think I have to add CASE in SELECT clause of second SQL and use first SQL in that CASE statement. But can't figure out how to get weekly average for past 4 weeks (4 numbers) instead of a single average.

**My Question:** How can I get result I want using single/multiple SQL? I can use a single SQL or multiple.

Comment: _This table will have percentage values of col_4 against col_5 in col_6. (col_5/col4 * 100)_. That's bad database design. Why should the column hold a calculated value of two other columns (even of the same table)? There's no reason to store that like that

Comment: I think it was to make the future calculations (like this one to get weekly averages) as easy as possible. But that is just my guess. I am just trying to use this table and don't know who created it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my go at this, it will output the right data but not in the format you want. You need to pivot the output first for that but maybe this is something that you can do easier when presenting the data.

The code below includes two weeks back but you can easily copy the second select and increase the interval in DATE_SUB accordingly

```
SELECT col_2, col_1, DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(), "%m/%d") as saturday, AVG(col_6)
FROM table_1
WHERE col_3 between DATE_SUB(sysdate(), interval 1 week) and sysdate()
GROUP BY col_2, col_1, saturday
UNION ALL
SELECT col_2, col_1, DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(sysdate(), interval 1 week), "%m/%d") as saturday, AVG(col_6)
FROM table_1
WHERE col_3 between DATE_SUB(sysdate(), interval 2 week) and date_sub(sysdate(), interval 1 week)
GROUP BY col_2, col_1, saturday
```